# Getting unmatched value from different list have common property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics

i have two generic value of type emp and principle
emp pojo

```
class emp
{
  Private String name;
  Private String Phone;
  Private Designation;
  //setters and getters
}
```

principle pojo

```
class principle
{
  Private String name;
  Private String lastName;
  Private String school;
  //setters and getters
}
```

I am having two list

```
List<emp> list=new ArrayList<emp>();
list=dao.getData();

List<principle> list1=new ArrayList<principle>();
list1=dao.getDataOfprinciple();
```

i have tried something like this

```
List<emp> list3=new ArrayList<emp>();
    for(emp e:list)
        {
            for(principle p:list1)
            {
                String x=e.getName();
            String y=p.getName();
            if(x==y)
            break;
            Reader reader=new Reader();
                reader.setMfrPn(r.getMfrPn());  
                reader.setMfrName(r.getMfrName());  
            list3.add(r);   
            }
           }
```

how do I  find the list of `emp` which are not matching with 
`principle` list with respect to name and I have to store the list in new list of type `emp`

Comment: What does this have to do with generics? Why are you creating lists and discarding them? Why don't you follow Java naming conventions?

Comment: That answers 0 questions.

Comment: can i use nested for each

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I'm happy to help, but I don't intend to write free code for you. That's not how this site works. And I wasn't pointing out mistakes so much as clarifying and suggesting.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions sir

Comment: You're on the right track, but you're adding too soon. You have to wait for the inner loop to complete first. One option is to add it after the inner loop and `continue outer;` if a match is found. Or you can do `List<emp> list3 = list.stream().filter(e -> list1.stream().noneMatch(e.getName()::equals)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Also, [don't use `==` to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Correction to the above: `list1.stream().map(principle::getName)`